# Get rid of pyximport

Tags: cython, spyder

I'm trying to use Cython. I use setup.py and build as opposed to letting pyximport do this. However, every time I import my module it seems pyximport is called. Pyximport fails to build and everything crashes.

I use Spyder. I do not have a single reference to pyximport in my project, but Spyder does not seem to care and keeps calling pyximprot.

I called my program from the command window (outside Spyder) and it ran just fine.

How can i get rid of the call to pyximport? Or is something else going on?

```
import c_result
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-3e92d1c50179>", line 1, in <module>
    import c_result

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 458, in load_module
language_level=self.language_level)

  File "C:\Users\xxxR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 231, in load_module
raise exc.with_traceback(tb)

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 215, in load_module
inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 191, in build_module
reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 102, in pyx_to_dll
dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 185, in run
_build_ext.build_ext.run(self)

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
self.build_extensions()

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 192, in build_extensions
ext.sources = self.cython_sources(ext.sources, ext)

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 327, in cython_sources
self.mkpath(os.path.dirname(target))

  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 338, in mkpath
dir_util.mkpath(name, mode, dry_run=self.dry_run)

 File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 74, in mkpath
"could not create '%s': %s" % (head, exc.args[-1]))

ImportError: Building module c_result failed: ["distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: could not create 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile': Kan ikke opprette en fil når filen allerede finnes\n"]
```

Comment: This is a fairly recent addition (early-mid 2017) to spyder, hence the bug is not "popular" yet. The problem is caused by the code [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py#L168). The only solution I see is to manually edit the `sitecustomize.py` file in your spyder installation and remove the section under `if HAS_PYXIMPORT:`

Comment: Hi. Thanks. That stopped spyder from calling pyximport. Now it is giving me  "ModuleNotFoundError" when i import. Again, calling from outside spyder works. You answered my question though, if you want to give your comment as an answer ill give you credit for it.

Comment: Can you give the full traceback for this new error? I'll prepare an answer anyway with links to the spyder issues opened on GitHub.

Comment: sure `import c_result as rs\
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-f94c457034c7>", line 1, in <module>
    import c_result as rs

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'c_result'`

Comment: what does `ls` return? (it is interpreted by ipython and will list the directory as the regular shell command).

Comment: it returns a lot :) but i guess you are wondering about these <DIR> build,c_result.c and c_result.cp35-win_amd64.pyd

Comment: given that `c_result.*.pyd` is in the directory, it should be imported properly. spyder does mess up with `sys.path`, can you print it? `import sys ; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Its too big to print but it does contain my project directory. Where the .pyd is located `[' ', 'C:\\Prosjekter\\Python\\Analyse', 'C:\\Users\\ac22376.ONEADR\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',....]`

Comment: does removing in addition the `import pyximport` line help (in the file sitecustomize.py)?

Comment: I see references to `python36` in the sys.path variable. The module is compiled with python 3.5. Can you recompile it with the proper python version?

Comment: I guess we are getting closer to the crux of the problem. Seems my default python version is 3.5.2 whilst spyder uses 3.6.something. Im on a computer where i currently have no admin rights... so I need to think about how to fix that :( Tried to switch in spyder. Spyder wasnt too happy about that

Comment: Well, that should be quite ok. Spyder uses anaconda (from the paths in the traceback). Compile with `C:\Users\ac22376.ONEADR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\bin\python3.6`. I don't know windows enough to recommend more advanced settings and will leave you at that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155340/discussion-between-mortysporty-and-pierre-de-buyl).

Comment: Sir, I kneel before you. It worked! Thank you. You saved me countless hours!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem appeared in Spyder because the package's initialization actually loads `pyximport` and calls `pyximport.install()`, in the file [utils/site/sitecustomize.py](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py#L168).

Other have complained about it on GitHub:

- [spyder issue #5299](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5299)
- [spyder issue #5087](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5087)

A solution that is not elegant (will not survive updates of spyder, for instance) but that should work is to manually edit the sitecustomize.py file in your spyder installation and remove the section under `if HAS_PYXIMPORT:`

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We're thinking how to fix this for Spyder **3.2.5**. I'll post an answer when we've decided what to do.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Possibly a user-editable setting?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what we're thinking to do. What do you think is more intuitive: an option in `Preferences > IPython console` or in `Run > Configuration per file` to activate our Cython support?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Is there a solution available in Spyder, today?

Comment: @jvermeulen, no there isn't. We'll fix this problem in our 3.2.8 version.

Answer (score 4):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem was fixed in our **3.2.8** version, released on March 2018.

Comment: I still saw the error but I had gotten my IPython console into a bad state with messed up imports. Once I restarted the kernel everything was fine.