# Importing Cython module fails in Spyder but not in regular python console

Tags: python, gcc, cython, spyder

**Disclaimer**: I am using anaconda and python2.7.

I just compiled a cython module `my_module.pyx` with `distutils` (build_ext --inplace) and the compilation went just fine. I can import it in any regular python console.

```
import my_module
```

But whenever I do it inside an Ipython console in spyder I get the not very helpful message:

```
ImportError: Building module my_module failed: ["CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1\n"]
```

I checked both paths using `sys` they are the same except that Ipython has some additional paths related to ipython utilities.

What could be the origin of these differences in behaviour ?

Comment: It might be related to this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422488/get-rid-of-pyximport. Essentially Spyder decided to autoimport pyimport which always tries to recompile Cython modules and makes it a complete disaster for using Cython. I'm not sure if they've fixed it yet.

Comment: Looking into that thanks !

Comment: It was exactly that ! Thanks @DavidW I will let you answer !

Comment: @DavidW, we finally fix it and it'll be part of our 3.2.8 release. Sorry for the mess, we didn't understand the effects of `pyximport` when we accepted the contribution of an external user to compile Cython directly in our consoles.

Comment: @Carloscordoba Good to know!

Comment: @Jean I've voted to close as a duplicate rather than answering... Glad the link helped.

Comment: I have accepted the duplication tag. Thanks @DavidW and the spyder team !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem was already [fixed](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/6607/files) and it'll be solved after our **3.2.8** version is released.